# Does the SGBD oracle always execute the queries of an anonymous plsql in the same order?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sequences

This a part of my code java constructing a function in an anonymous plsql block:

```
*String p ="FUNCTION get_result RETURN varchar2 AS "
+"BEGIN "
+"sql_error:='ok';"
+query1+";"
+query2+";"
+query3+";"
+"COMMIT;"
+"RETURN sql_error; "
+"EXCEPTION "
+"when others then "
+"ROLLBACK;"
+"end;";*
```

where queries 1,2 and 3 are sql queries; sometimes query2 is not executed and this does not generate a transaction error and queries 1 and 3 and committed. I would like to Know how is it possible and, how can I correct it.
I would like also to know which procedure is better between **calling anonymous block statements** and **statement.addBatch**

I want to know how the manage sessions that execute transaction that manipulate many sequences. 
I found that using many seauences in a transaction causes errors that oracle do not send back to the user. Do they sometimes get the same value for 2 executions on sequence.nextval ?
thank you

Comment: That's a function, not an anonymous block; but yes for both the statements in a PL/SQL block will always run in the same order. Your query2 is always executed, if the function is called with that definition. (This is a really odd design, BTW). Without knowing anything about the statements or data, or when this code or the function are called, it's impossible to say why it appears to you that it isn't executed.

Comment: Can Oracle use many threads to execute a procedure ?

Comment: You mean execute the same procedure simultaneously from multiple client sessions? Yes. Or use threads internally while executing one instance? I imagine so, possibly to different extents on different platforms. Each call will be logically intact though, statements within a block will be executed in the order you specify. You could see apparently odd things from simultaneous calls, depending on what the procedure is doing, and if/when it commits, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the bug I was creating.
I fact, all the queries were not in the same transaction, due to the fact that I was using a static attribute that was collecting the queries of various transactions and sending them to the SGBD oracle through anonymous plsql.

so I changed the static variable to simple and public one, collector of the queries assessed through an instance of the class, so that all the queries of a transaction should be always sent at once and executed in the same order.